# What's wrong with this link?

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

We are using this link to delete data from an MySQL database, but when we launch it in the browser we get an error that something is wrong with this line.
Could someone say what's wrong with it?

```
echo "<a href=delete_hardware.php?id=<?php.$rows['hardwareID']; ?>>delete</a>";
```

Comment: Where am I missing the double quotes?

Comment: You even got syntax highlighting. It cant be too hard to locate the problem now.

Comment: You're actually opening a new `<?php` tag while you're already in a php tag (the `echo` part). Consider just concatenating by `".."`. Also just put single quotes around a `href`, i don't like when urls given like than, source of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "<a href=delete_hardware.php?id=" .$rows['hardwareID'] .">delete</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks man it works now!!! Been searching for a while.

Comment: I can do that in 8 minutes

Comment: @niekerd May not want to be too hasty with that check mark - sometimes answers take time to write, that's why the 15-minute limit exists ;)

Comment: This looks like invalid HTML. Attributes should have quotes like `<a href="http://domain.tld">Link text</a>`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correct link, with quotes and concatenation :

```
echo '<a href="delete_hardware.php?id='.$rows['hardwareID'].'">delete</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using a *link* to perform a *destructive* action.

Never, *ever*, **ever**, ***EVER*** use `<a href...>` to *perform an action*. **Especially** not a "delete" action.

`GET` requests imply that they may be performed at any time, without any need for confirmation. `POST` requests, on the other hand, imply one-time use. This is why when you reload a page you opened through a link, that's fine, but try to reload a page you submitted with a form? HOLD ON THERE, are you sure you want to resubmit because you might end up buying the same item twice!

Therefore, your code should be:

```
?>
<form action="delete_hardware.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=intval($rows['hardwareID'])?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="delete" onClick="return confirm('Are you SURE you want to delete this?');" />
</form>
<?php
```